# Bypass/Ignore "no audio device" error

Tags: python, windows, audio

This is a known problem for Windows users, you can't watch YouTube or play/use applications, because you don't have an audio device and the app shows an error messages or simply crashes.

I want to avoid this on my **Python game** that I am currently making, but I couldn't find anything useful on the web, has anyone a solution?